# How to use jquery Attr() to select only first attribute?

Tags: jquery

I have a div as follows:

```
<DIV CLASS="variable productPopup"></DIV>
```

When assigning it to a var, how do I only select variable? Please note that variable changes, so it needs to select the first item, not literally the words "variable"

```
var ID = $(this).attr("class");
```

Comment: Please note that jquery has `hasClass()` and `add/removeAttr()` methods. Maybe you can use that instead of manually splitting the string.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get the first class mentioned, you can split the value by spaces:

```
var firstClass = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0];
```

So if the class attribute was "foo Bar", you'd get "foo".